# LNK2019 Error at template function of my class

Tags: c++, c++11, lnk2019

i got the following error

"Fehler 9   error LNK2019: Verweis auf nicht aufgelöstes externes Symbol ""public: bool __cdecl gameClass::getAttribute(class std::basic_string,class std::allocator >)" (??$getAttribute@_N@gameClass@@QEAA_NV?$basic_string@DU?$char_traits@D@std@@V?$allocator@D@2@@std@@@Z)" in Funktion "main". C:\Users\Weexe\documents\visual studio 2010\Projects\Engine\Engine\main.obj Engine
"

My Code 
class.h

```
template <typename T> T getAttribute(std::string attribute);
```

class.cpp

```
template <typename T>
T gameClass::getAttribute(std::string attribute)
{
std::map<std::string,int> matchAttribute;

matchAttribute["windowTitle"]=1;
matchAttribute["windowSizeX"]=2;
matchAttribute["windowSizeY"]=3;
matchAttribute["isMenue"]=4;

switch(matchAttribute[attribute])
{
case 1:
    return this->windowTitle;
    break;
case 2:
    return this->windowSizeX;
    break;
case 3:
    return this->windowSizeY;
    break;
case 4:
    return this->isMenue;
    break;
}
}
```

Any one have an idear how to fix that error ? 
I think its a syntax error or smth like that :/

Comment: Also it looks like someone played a prank on you and changed the OS language to German.

Comment: It's not a prank , i am a german.

Comment: Oh - sorry about that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Templates can only be implemented in header files (.h, .hpp, .inl) e.t.c. This means that the code in class .cpp wil have to be 'bonded' with the code in class.h, to make a new header file.

Comment: Oh, nice to know !
so i only need to past my code in the header file ? I'll give it a try.